# jQuery droppable not working for certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a page in which I want to drag some draggable elements from right-hand side pane and drop it to the central pane which is occupied by png images of a document.
Snippet of the page:

```
<div class="row PDF_Main  margTB20" id="pdfview">
<div class="PDF_View">
    <div class="page">
        <div class='document-reader' id="document-reader">
            <input type="hidden" id="fileName" value="<c:out value="${filename}"></c:out>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After an ajax call some images are getting added to the document-reader div dynamically:

```
$("#document-reader").append('<div class="drop" id="'+i+'"><img width="'+width+'px" height="'+height+'px" class="render-image" onload="loadImage()" src="data:image/png;base64,'+<c:out value='response'></c:out>+'"></div>');
```

Now I want to use the div with drop class as jQuery droppable. But it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".dragSigners").draggable({
     helper: 'clone',
     cursor: 'move',
     tolerance: 'fit',
     revert: true 
});
$(".drop").droppable({
    accept : ".dragSigners",
    activeClass : "drop-area",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        alert("dropped");
        ui.helper.remove();
        leftPosition  = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
        topPosition   = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
        alert("left position "+leftPosition);
        alert("top position "+topPosition);
    }
});
});
```

**However instead of using jQuery class selector for "drop", if we use 'document-reader', it works.** As you you see 'document-reader' is class for parent div - I do not want to make it droppable as there could be multiple images & hence multiple divs with 'drop' class & want to make these divs droppable. Why it is not recognizing divs with drop class as droppable? And why  the draggable element is reverting back to its original position as if it has not been dragged to a droppable?

**Edit** One more problem is the dragged element is reverting back even if we make revert: false

**Edit2** This very code works in some other page

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store your jQuery Draggable options as a global variable and use it with the `.droppable()` call when adding dynamic content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // droppable options
    var dropOptions = {
        accept : ".dragSigners",
        activeClass : "drop-area",
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
            ui.helper.remove();
            leftPosition  = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
            topPosition   = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
            alert("left position "+leftPosition);
            alert("top position "+topPosition);
        }
    }

    // Set draggable/droppable on page load
    $(".dragSigners").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        revert: true
    });

    $(".drop").droppable(dropOptions);

    // Dynamic content stored as a jQuery object
    var newContent = $('<div class="drop"><img /></div>');

    // Append and set droppable options.
    newContent.appendTo("#document-reader").droppable(dropOptions);
})
```

Comment: Tried your solution. It has not worked. And ain't we making newContent draggable twice,once dynamically when the images are getting appended & again at document load time.

Comment: When dynamic elements are appended to the document they won't be draggable/droppable/anything else because you call `$(".drop").droppable(dropOptions);` on *page load* - it doesn't account for anything appended afterwards.

Comment: ok got it. However as this is not working.Thank you though for answering